# XML Node value update with XQuery

Tags: java

Im using XQuery in my Project, and to execute XQueries im using SAXON9 from JAVA.

Here the problem is when im trying to update a node value im getting an exception.
I don't have any problems with selecting the data from xml file using XQuery.The only problem im facing is with data modification through xquery.

This is my query:
replace value of node (for $fname in doc("D:/contacts.xml")/Directory/Contacts/Contact[@id='0045d6cd-2c79-4a8d-879b-e8b0b9bfd16e']/LastName return $fname) 
with 'foo'.

This is the Exception:
javax.xml.xquery.XQException: Unexpected token "replace value" in path expression.

Can anyone tell me that do i need to any configuration settings in SAXON9 for executing the above query successfully.

I heard that there is a configuration setting for Update in xquery. how can i do that in SAXON.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the EE version, AFAIK you're out of luck.

For enabling updates from Java, use the [`XQueryCompiler.setUpdatingEnabled()` method](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XQueryCompiler.html#setUpdatingEnabled%28boolean%29).

From the command line use the `update:on` switch.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have done as your suggested but still im getting same problem. Can you send the code showing that how to execute the update query using SAXON9ee from JAVA.

Comment: Here is my code is there any wrong? XQDataSource ds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
XQConnection conn = ds.getConnection();
XQExpression expr = conn.createExpression();
String query = "replace value of node ....";
IndependentContext context = new IndependentContext();
XPathEvaluator xPathEvaluator = new XPathEvaluator();
xPathEvaluator.setStaticContext(context);
Configuration conf = xPathEvaluator.getConfiguration();
Processor process = new Processor(conf);
XQueryCompiler compiler = process.newXQueryCompiler();
compiler.setUpdatingEnabled(true);
XQResultSequence result = expr.executeQuery(query);

Comment: Can't really read that, but you're calling `setUpdatingEnabled`, so that part is correct. Are you using the EE version?

Answer (score 0):

You may be more successful with some other open source, yet complete XQuery Update implementations (BaseX, MonetDB, Sedna).